# How to retrieve string value from a json using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

My site stores strings in a json file and uses javascript to retrive value to HTML. Here's simplified version of the function.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  This is a demonstration. The author is:
    <div>
      <div class="author"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'data.json', true);

request.onload = function () {
   obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
   obj.forEach(function (d) {
        var el = document.createElement('p');
        el.textContent = d.author;
        document.getElementsByClassName('author')[0].appendChild(el);
    });
};

request.send();
```

Json:

```
{
  "author": "John Doe"
}
```

Implementation: http://embed.plnkr.co/Ixrz9R2KVLXpOqa7mwyU

The code doesn't return author name in the HTML. Is there anyway to do this without using jQuery if possible.

Comment: Is your json an array of objects?

Comment: In my actual office json, it is an array. But this code is still not working.

Comment: Instead of editing the question title, accept the answer that provided a solution to you. You can do this by clicking on the tick icon to the left of an answer. StackOverflow has a built-in system to tag solved/answered questions automatically.

Comment: In the same vein, do not add the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The reason

You have to load scripts like this:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

---

## The solution

Remove

```
<link href="script.js">
```

, and put

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

onto right before the `</body>`.

I recommend you put your script onto right before the `</body>` in order to let it be executed after the DOM elements are loaded.

---

## The code

#### data.json

```
[
    {"author": "K."},
    {"author": "Hello world"},
    {"author": "John Doe"}
]
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="K.">

    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>This is a demonstration. The author is:</p>
    <div class="author"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### script.js

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest; // `()` isn't needed.
request.open("GET", "data.json", true);
request.addEventListener("load", _ => { // Arrow function
    const parsed = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    parsed.forEach(({author}) => { // Destructuring, Arrow function, ...
        const authorElement = document.createElement("P");
        authorElement.textContent = author;
        document.querySelector(".author").appendChild(authorElement);
    });
});
request.send();
```